# Minor monotone chromatic numbers

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I am studying graphs $G$ for which $\chi(H)<\chi(G)$ for all minors $H$ of $G$. Complete graphs are examples of such graphs and bipartite graphs (except $K_2$) are nonexamples.

Are there any characterizations or nice properties of this kind of graphs? In particular we may look at the ones on $n$ vertices with minimum number of edges. I would appreciate  your thoughts or relevant references.

Answer (score 2):

[Hadwiger's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadwiger_conjecture_(graph_theory)) is equivalent to the claim that complete graphs are the only such graphs.

In one direction: if a graph $G$ with $\chi(G) = k$ has $K_k$ as a minor, then it has a minor $H$ with $\chi(H) = \chi(G)$, so it fails to have this property. So if Hadwigers'c conjecture holds, the only graphs with this property are complete graphs.

In the other: if complete graphs are the only graphs with this property, then for any other graph $G$ we may pass to a minor $H$ with $\chi(H) \ge \chi(G)$, and repeat until we are left with a complete graph, which implies Hadwiger's conjecture.

---

All such graphs, if they exist, must be [critical graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_graph). This ensures, also, that contracting any one edge reduces the chromatic number. However, it may be that contracting further edges later on will bring the chromatic number back up.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I was aware how Hadwiger conjecture implies this. But can you elaborate how Hadwiger conjecture is implied by the statement that complete graphs are the only graphs with the above property?

Comment: For as long as we have a non-complete graph, we may take a minor that does not decrease the chromatic number. If we repeat, the number of vertices keeps decreasing while the chromatic number does not decrease, so this process can only end in a complete graph of at least the required size.